# Efficient data store for storing and retrieving Map<Integer,Integer> data structures, and incrementing their values

Tags: java, database

I'm looking for a technology very similar in function to [count-db](https://github.com/koendeschacht/count-db).

> Use case
>
> You want to use count-db if you need to write and read billions of
>   counts very efficiëntly from a Java program. Use cases are logging
>   large amounts of user data, counting n-grams for language models or
>   building an index to search texts. You don't want to use count-db if
>   you require transactions or my-sql style querying.

I need to be able to do these things with it:

1. Store data whose logical structure is similar to the `Map<Integer,Integer>`   data type

   - At the minimum, 200 entries in size each
2. Atomically increment a subset of the `Map`'s values by 1 given a list of ~15 `Integer`  keys

   - Assume this is done 10,000/s on average, but the tech recommendation should have the
     capability of scaling out
3. Get an entire `Map`'s values based on an Integer key

   - So structurally, the data store should be organized like `Map<Integer,Map<Integer,Integer>>`
   - Assume getting an entire `Map` is done 1,000/s on average

`count-db` captures the spirit of what I'm trying to do -- strictly counting and retrieving integers. The reason I'm not using it is because it doesn't seem to offer storing `Map` data types, so getting an entire `Map` would require doing 200 key-value pair lookups for something that should logically require 1. And also, the only documentation there is about it is its homepage on github -- a single, short `Java` example. There's not even comments in the source code.